# How to setState for array immediately?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

I ran into one problem connected with updating state in react.

Well, I have some data and I want to build a table with this data. But, I would like to filter it first. The filtration is working well, but I only have problem with updating filtered data and throwing it to the next component... (I know that setState is not working immediately...)

updatedReports in ReportTable component still has not filtered data...
What is the best way to fix it and to work with updating state for arrays.

```
export default class ReportContent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentReports: this.props.reports
    };
}

_filterBy(option) {
    let updatedReports = [...this.props.reports].filter(report => {
        if (report.organizations === option || report.reportType === option) {
            return report;
        }
    });
    console.log(updatedReports);
    this.setState({currentReports: updatedReports});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="reports-table">
            <ReportMenu organizations={this.props.organizations} reportTypes={this.props.reportTypes}
                        filterBy={this._filterBy.bind(this)}/>
            <ReportTable updatedReports={this.state.currentReports}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code except maybe the structure of your `option` parameter in `_filterBy` method. Can you post your `ReportMenu` component and the structure of your `option` parameter.

Comment: @jpdelatorre option parameter is fine... when I log updatedReports - I got what I want... The problem is that currentReports are not updated  immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you provided. `setState` should work if invoked correctly. My bet is the problem is within your other components or the data.

Here's a snippet that uses your code. I have no idea how you implement your other components so I just made some assumptions here.

```
class ReportMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="well well-default">
            <select className="form-control" onChange={(e) => {
                this.props.filterBy(e.target.value)
            }}>
                <option> - </option>
                {this.props.organizations.map(
                    (item, index) => <option key={index}>{item}</option>
                )}
            </select>
            <br/>
            <select className="form-control" onChange={(e) => {
                this.props.filterBy(e.target.value)
            }}>
                <option> - </option>
                {this.props.reportTypes.map(
                    (item, index) => <option key={index}>{item}</option>
                )}
            </select>
        </div>
    }
}

class ReportTable extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <table className="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                {this.props.updatedReports.map(
                    (item, index) => <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{index}</td>
                        <td>{item.organizations}</td>
                        <td>{item.reportType}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}

class ReportContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentReports: this.props.reports
        };
    }
    _filterBy(option) {
        let updatedReports = this.props.reports.filter(report => {
            if (report.organizations === option || report.reportType === option) {
                return report;
            }
        });
        console.log(updatedReports);
        this.setState({currentReports: updatedReports});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="reports-table">
                <ReportMenu 
                    organizations={this.props.organizations} 
                    reportTypes={this.props.reportTypes} 
                    filterBy={this._filterBy.bind(this)}/>
                <ReportTable updatedReports={this.state.currentReports}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const reports = [
            {
                organizations: 'orgA',
                reportType: 'typeA'
            }, {
                organizations: 'orgA',
                reportType: 'typeB'
            }, {
                organizations: 'orgB',
                reportType: 'typeA'
            }, {
                organizations: 'orgB',
                reportType: 'typeB'
            }
        ];
        return <div className="container">
            <h1 className="page-header">Reports</h1>
            <ReportContent 
                reports={reports} 
                organizations={['orgA', 'orgB']} 
                reportTypes={['typeA', 'typeB']}/>
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You are right! I have en extra state in my ReportTable component... now the passing props are correct... BUT know I have another problem with:

`Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

Comment: That issue would require more info to figure out and totally different from your initial question. Might be good idea to marked this question answered and post another one with a more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use the component lifecycle methods. [Here is more info.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

`componentDidMount` should do the trick. You can do something like this :

```
componentDidMount(){
    let updatedReports = [...this.props.reports].filter(report => {
        if (report.organizations === option || report.reportType === option) {
            return report;
        }
    });
    this.setState({currentReports: updatedReports});
}
```

Or just call your method `_filterBy` inside componentDidMount.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I don't know what to do with 'option' param, which I get from child component...

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: sorry, but it's too many code there... and I don't know exactly how to put a short and correct example of the same situation..